# What is (was) "wrong" with Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jruby

I've been using Tomcat for quite a while, I even understand it's embeding (introduced in Tomcat 7) APIs quite well, as I maintained Trinidad a JRuby (e.g. suitable for deployinh Ruby on Rails applications) server built upon Tomcat.

Every once in a while, there's a kind of "myth" (for me) recommendation to not use Tomcat and instead of alternatives such as Jetty. It's somehow never explained and I'd like to know more as it seems to be coming from experienced Java-ists e.g. I first heard it from a Square talk about how they deploy (JRuby) applications: http://vimeo.com/45719570

Not sure how and if it is still relevant but even going back a few years I'd like to know the background of "stay away from Tomcat" ... esp. as it seems to still pop-up and some still do not want to use a Tomcat "based solution" : [JRuby deployment options that support multiple versions of JRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585102/jruby-deployment-options-that-support-multiple-versions-of-jruby)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Tomcat. I used it for loading my Jsp pages when I was developing Spring web framework based servlet. However, I experienced memory leaks and crashes with Tomcat. Before you jump out and say "Memory Leak using Java??", I think it was not my code, but it was something to do with Tomcat and Java version that we were using. We never got to the core of the problem and decided to just carry on as it happened only 1/2 a day. Apart from that, tomcat is not a bad tool to use I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, could you share more details such as Tomcat/Java versions ... I also experienced leaks but it was never Tomcat (7)'s fault and it's leak detection code turned actually quite valuable compared to others as I was able to get hints where the leaks are coming from.

Comment: My problem was that when I was trying to launch my servlet (as I mentioned before, 1/2 a day over a 10 hours' worth of activities), the log window showed some message (can't remember now) saying that there was a memLeak error. I know that people would say"Why don't you increase your Vm memory genious?". But it actually doesn't work. You gotta remember that Windows is in charge and Java VM is simply another application that can force windows to give a bit more memory (but not much). This was the only issue I had. Solution was to restart tomcat service.